# How can I retrieve all members when querying for appRoleAssignedTo in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to programmatically retrieve a list of users (`principalType = "User"`) and their associated `appRoleId` values for an enterprise app using its`resourceId` value from `Azure AD`.  There is a total of ten `Users` with a combined total of twenty `appRoleId` values associated with the app.  However, when I run my query I receive data for just two users and a combined total of four `appRoleId` values.

Here's my C# code:

```
GraphServiceClient myGraphClient = GetGraphServiceClient([scopes]);
// Retrieve the [Id] value for the app.  Note [Id] is a pseudonym for the [resourceId] required to retrieve users and app roles assigned.
var servPrinPage = await myGraphClient.ServicePrincipals.Request()
   .Select("id,appRoles")
   .Filter($"startswith(displayName, 'Display Name')")
   .GetAsync()
   .ConfigureAwait(false);
// Using the first [Id] value from the [ServicePrincipals] page, retrieve the list of users and their assigned roles for the app.
var appRoleAssignedTo = await myGraphClient.ServicePrincipals[servPrinPage[0].Id].AppRoleAssignedTo.Request().GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The query returns a `ServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignedToCollectionPage` (as expected) but the collection only contains four pages (one per `User/appRoleId` combination).

As an aside, the following query in Microsoft Graph Explorer produces an equivalent result:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/[resourceId]/appRoleAssignedTo
```

What am I missing here?  I need to be able to retrieve the complete list of users and assigned app roles.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I was confronting has to do with the pagination feature employed by `Azure AD` and `MS Graph`.  In a nutshell, I was forced to submit two queries in order to retrieve all twenty records I was expecting.

If you have a larger set of records to be retrieved you may be faced with submitting a much larger number of successive queries. The successive queries are managed using a "skiptoken" passed as a request header each time your query is resubmitted.

Here is my revised code with notation....

```
// Step #1:  Create a class in order to strongly type the <List> which will hold your results.
// Not absolutely necessary but always a good idea when working with <Lists> in C#.

private class AppRoleByUser
{
    public string AzureDisplayName;
    public string PrincipalDisplayName;
}

// Step #2: Submit a query to acquire the [id] for the Service Principal (i.e. your app).
// Note the [ServicePrincipals].[id] property is synonymous with the [resourceId] needed to 
// retrieve [AppRoleAssignedTo] values from Microsoft Graph in the next step.

// Initialize the Microsoft Graph Client.
GraphServiceClient myGraphClient = GetGraphServiceClient("Directory.Read.All");

// Retrieve the Service Principals page containing the app [Id].
var servPrinPage = await myGraphClient.ServicePrincipals.Request().Select("id,appRoles").Filter($"startswith(displayName, 'Your App Name')").GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

// Store the app [Id] in a local variable (for readability).
string resourceId = servPrinPage[0].Id;

// Step #3: Using the [Id]/[ResourceId] value from the previous step, retrieve a list of AppRoleId/DisplayName pairs for your app.

// Results of the successive queries are typed against the class created earlier and are appended to the <List>.
List<AppRoleByUser> appRoleByUser  = new List<AppRoleByUser>();

// Note, unlike "Filter" or "Search" parameters, it is not possible to
// add a "Skiptoken" parameter directly to your query in C#.  
// Instead, it is necessary to insert the "skiptoken" as request header using the Graph QueryOption class.
// Note the QueryOption List is passed as an empty object on the first pass of the while loop.
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>();

// Initialize the variable to hold the anticipated query result.
ServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignedToCollectionPage appRoleAssignedTo = new ServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignedToCollectionPage();

// Note the number of user/role combinations associated with an app is not always known.
// Consequently, you may be faced with the need to acquire multiple pages 
// (and submit multiple consecutive queries) in order to obtain a complete 
// listing of user/role combinations.
// The "while" loop construct will be utilized to manage query iteration.
// Execution of the "while" loop will be stopped when the "bRepeat" variable is set to false.

bool bRepeat = true;
while (bRepeat == true)
{
    appRoleAssignedTo = (ServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignedToCollectionPage) await myGraphClient.ServicePrincipals[resourceId].AppRoleAssignedTo.Request(queryOptions).GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    foreach (AppRoleAssignment myPage in appRoleAssignedTo)
    {
        // I was not able to find a definitive answer in any of the documents I
        // found but it appears the final record in the recordset carries a 
        // [PrincipalType] = "Group" (all others carry a [PrincipalType] = "User").
        if (myPage.PrincipalType != "Group")
        {
            // Insert "User" data into the List<AppRoleByUser> collection.
            appRoleByUser.Add(new AppRoleByUser{ AzureDisplayName = myPage.PrincipalDisplayName, AzureUserRole = myPage.AppRoleId.ToString() });
        }
        else
        {
            // The "bRepeat" variable is initially set to true and is set to 
            // false when the "Group" record is detected thus signaling 
            // task completion and closing execution of the "while" loop.
            bRepeat = false;
        }
    }
    // Acquire the "nextLink" string from the response header. 
    // The "nextLink" string contains the "skiptoken" string required for the next 
    // iteration of the query.
    string nextLinkValue = appRoleAssignedTo.AdditionalData["@odata.nextLink"].ToString();

    // Parse the "skiptoken" value from the response header.
    string skipToken = nextLinkValue.Substring(nextLinkValue.IndexOf("=") + 1);

    // Include the "skiptoken" as a request header in the next iteration of the query.
    queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
    {
        new QueryOption("$skiptoken", skipToken)
    };
}
```

That's a long answer to what should have been a simple question.  I am relatively new to `Microsoft Graph` but it appears to me `Microsoft` has a long way to go in making this API developer-friendly.  All I needed was to know the combination of AppRoles and Users associated with a single, given `Azure AD` app.  One query and one response should have been more than sufficient.

At any rate, I hope my toil might help save time for someone else going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please remove "Filter" from the code and retry the operation. Let us know if that worked.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Unfortunately, my issue is not with the first query.  The first query uses the filter method to facilitate retrieving the ```[id]``` value for my app.  This value is the pseudonym for the ```[resourceId]``` value which is required in the second query.

Comment: My problem is with the second query not allowing all records to be selected.  The comments from soumi-MSFT in the following link provide more detail as to the two-part process required for extraction of app roles on a per-user basis:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/51813/where-can-we-find-the-id-of-the-resource-servicepr.html.    I used this as my guide.